# How to make functions get called sequentially in JS?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am making a webpage where once the user clicks on the **start** button, some changes will happen to the CSS of the page (I wrote the required JavaScript (JS) code). Only after these changes happen, I want some other changes to happen. In an attempt to achieve this, I wrote calls to 2 functions inside the function that gets called once the event happens: (In the below JS code, the 2 functions begin called inside the function that which gets triggered by the "click" event are- **startCountdown** and **showWords**)

```
document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click",startTheGame);
function startTheGame()
{
    var contentSlides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    // Game started so we are hiding the start slide!
    contentSlides[0].classList.add("hideDisplay"); 
    //
    // Now the "321 Go!" down timer is to be shown!
    contentSlides[1].classList.remove("hideDisplay");
    startCountdown(document.getElementById("onClickCount"));
    showWords();
    //
}
function startCountdown(reqElement)
{
    var time = 2;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function ()
    { 
        reqElement.innerText = time; 
        if(time==="Go!")
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        time-=1; 
        if(time===0)
            time = "Go!";
    },1000);
}
function showWords()
{
    alert("Hi!");
}
```

In the **showWords** function also, I wish to make some changes to the page. But, I want it to get executed only after the **startCountdown** function gets executed **completely**. As of now when I am running the above code, as soon as I click on the button, the alert is popping up! - But I don't want it to happen.

What changes do I need to make?

(After the **showWords** function gets executed completely - I want one more function to be executed - in this way I want the functions to be executed sequentially - i.e. the changes must happen in a specific order.)

Thanks for the help!

P.S.: Please let me know if you aren't able to understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so when it's  called clearInterval like this

```js
document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click",startTheGame);
function startTheGame()
{
    var contentSlides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    // Game started so we are hiding the start slide!
    contentSlides[0].classList.add("hideDisplay"); 
    //
    // Now the "321 Go!" down timer is to be shown!
    contentSlides[1].classList.remove("hideDisplay");
    startCountdown(document.getElementById("onClickCount"));    //
}
function startCountdown(reqElement)
{
    var time = 2;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function ()
    { 
        reqElement.innerText = time; 
        if(time === 0){
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            reqElement.innerText = "Go!"
            showWords();
        }
        time--; 

    },1000);
}
function showWords()
{
    alert("Hi!");
}
```

Comment: yes because asnychronous javascript is such that if you call a normal function and the async function, they are not sequentially dependant, so you would need the first function to call the second function instead.. answer's already given